# JSON.net Serialize C# object to JSON Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize a C# object to JSON using JSON.net library. The issue I am having is the string being created has &quot's in it.

Below is the string returned via JsonConvert.SerializeObject:

```
{
    &quot;ComId&quot;: &quot;AAAiB+AAHAALOaFAAL&quot;,
    &quot;CovId&quot;: &quot;AAABC9AAPAAAZYUAAI&quot;,
    &quot;EffectiveDate&quot;: &quot;\\/Date(1329368400000-0500)\\/&quot;,
    &quot;ExpirationDate&quot;: &quot;\\/Date(1360990800000-0500)\\/&quot;,
    &quot;State&quot;: &quot;TX&quot;,
    &quot;DeductibleAmount&quot;: 500.0,
    &quot;DeductibleType&quot;: &quot;PD&quot;
}
```

Running the string through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) returns:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    &quot;ComId&quot;: &
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Below is the object I am trying to serialize into JSON:

```
public class CommonInfoModel
{
    public virtual string ComId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CovId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Effective Date")]
    public virtual DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
    public virtual DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public virtual string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Deductible Amount")]
    public virtual decimal DeductibleAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Deductible Type")]
    public virtual string DeductibleType { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have searched and it seems others who use the method get cleaner strings! Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Why don't you make a replace of that &quot; from " and then parse it

Comment: How are you using JSON? Are you returning it from a Controller Action? Have you tried `return Json(model);`?

Comment: This is `{"ComId":null, "CovId":null,"EffectiveDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0200)\/", "ExpirationDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0200)\/", "State":null, "DeductibleAmount":0.0,"DeductibleType":null}` what I get when I run **`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CommonInfoModel())`**. You must be doing something with your string after serialization

Comment: do you have method like SerializeObject(Object, Formatting, JsonSerializerSettings) so you could handle the formatting/setting ?

Comment: @jrummell This is a dry run I am working on, but I am trying to convert a MVC Model to a JSON object and passing it via JQuery. ie $.ajax({ data: { json : "@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)" } ....

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Your json string is being HTML encoded. Since you're rendering the json in your view, you can use the `@Html.Raw()` helper to prevent it from being encoded.

```
var data = { json : "@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))" };
```

Comment: Thank you, by using Html.Raw I was able to clean up the string!

Comment: this rocks! Thank you!

Comment: Gotta be careful with this, @Html.Raw bypasses Razor's validation which opens up your page to an XSS vulnerability (if your model has string values with <script>, etc.)

Comment: This worked for me: `var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));`