# C# - "&quot;" causing issue with deserialization

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have an issue where I get an oldly formated json string with `&quot ;` instead of `\ "`. When I try to derserialize with `&quot ;` it fails. So I manually changed it to `\ "` but it still is failing. Here is my process:

For reference my json looks like so:

```
{
  "Contact": {
      "ToLine": "me@aol.com",
      "CCLine": "you@aol.com"
  }
}
```

I have a string being returned to me like this:

```
string myString = "{&quot;Contact&quot;:{&quot;ToLine&quot;:&quot;me@aol.com&quot;,&quot;CCLine&quot;:&quot;you@aol.com&quot;}}"
```

I then used the following to change it to what a json string should look like:

```
string jsonString = myString.Replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

Which makes:

```
string jsonString = "{\"Contact\":{\"ToLine\":\"me@aol.com\",\"CCLine\":\"you@aol.com\"}}"
```

Then when I call to deserialize:

```
CustomModel myModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomModel>(jsonString);
```

But I get an error saying:

```
Invalid property identifier character: &. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know how to take the string with "&quot ;" and get it into an object? Thanks!

Comment: The code you list works for me UNLESS I don't perform the replacement of "&quot;" with "\"".  Are you certain the replacement is working? In the first and last sentence of your post (but not in your code) "&quot ;" contains a space between "t" and the semicolon.

Comment: Also see the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331195/json-net-serialize-c-sharp-object-to-json-issue/9331581

Comment: @EricMunn I had to put a space in between the t and ; because if I don't, StackOverflow reads it as the command for ". So it would show up as """. Which ruins the explanation.

Comment: For future reference, if you need to do something like that, make it really obvious and mention it in your post so that everyone can know what you did

Comment: You have double-serialization going on: the object is serialized to JSON, then the JSON string is serialized again. Fix that at source: where the serialization is happening

Comment: `CustomModel myModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomModel>(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(myString))`. Maybe investigate why you got back an encoded string.